# C# Html in RichTextBox Wpf

Tags: html, wpf, string, richtextbox

Hi i have a class Question with a htmlstring, so the htmlstring contains for example `<b>network</b>`
but how Can i show this string in a richtextbox that the the string will be shown like this => **network** , so without the tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for HtmlToXaml conversion?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx